# What is wrong with this bower.json?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, bower

I'm using following bower.json:

```
{
  "name": "angularSeedApp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-material": "~1.1.0",
    "angular-animate": "1.5.9",
    "angular-aria": "1.5.9",
    "angular-material-icons": "x",
    "material-design-icons": "x",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.5.0",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.5.0",
    "angular-resource": "~1.4.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.17.0",
    "angular": "~1.5.0",
    "angular-filter": "x",
    "fontawesome": "~4.3.0",
    "hello": "^1.14.0",
    "cloudinary_ng": "^1.0.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.10",
    "angular-timezone-selector": "^1.6.0",
    "moment-range": "^2.1.0",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "~1.5.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "~1.5.0",
    "lodash": "4.0.1",
    "moment": ">= 1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.10"
  }
}
```

My problem is following -> A friend of mine was working on the project for a long time - and all the files get served from the src folder instead of dist folder. Now when I build the project all the libs get not detected anymore - so serving from dist produces the typical angular error "module not found".

The reason why I think it has to do with the bower_components:
When I pulled the project the bower_components were not updated - so it worked. After updating the bower_components it showed me these errors. So I believe it has to do with bower libs.

We are using this base setup: https://github.com/PauloLuan/angular-gulp-seed

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this bower.json? 
Can you also give me hints how to approach these kind of bugs?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is basically to use fixed versions for all angular-(resources).

```
  {
  "name": "angularSeedApp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "angular-material": "1.1.3",
    "angular-animate": "1.5.9",
    "angular-aria": "1.5.9",
    "angular-material-icons": "x",
    "material-design-icons": "x",
    "angular-cookies": "1.5.9",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.5.9",
    "angular-resource": "1.5.9",
    "angular-messages": "1.5.9",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.17.0",
    "angular-filter": "x",
    "fontawesome": "~4.3.0",
    "hello": "^1.14.0",
    "cloudinary_ng": "^1.0.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.10",
    "angular-timezone-selector": "^1.6.0",
    "moment-range": "^2.1.0",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "angular": "1.5.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "1.5.9"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "moment": ">= 2.6.0",
    "angular": "1.5.9",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.10",
    "lodash": "4.0.1"
  }
}
```